# Getting the content of specific tab using mshtml controls in C#

Tags: c#, web-crawler, mshtml, microsoft.mshtml

```
 <UL CLASS="littletab">
<LI CLASS="littletabitem" ID="forwardTo1">
    <A HREF="javascript:void(0)">Section 1</A>
    </LI>
<LI CLASS="littletabitem is-current">
    <A HREF="javascript:void(0)">Section 2</A>
    </LI>
<LI CLASS="littletabitem" ID="forwardTo3">
    <A HREF="javascript:void(0)">Section 3</A>
    </LI>
</UL>
```

I want to get the content the Section 1 and Section 3 tab using MSHTML Controls.

below is the code i have done so far.

```
                HTMLDocument myDoc2 = new HTMLDocumentClass();
                myDoc2 = (HTMLDocument)IE.Document;
                string Content_main2 = ((mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass)(IE.Document)).body.innerHTML;
                    HTMLAnchorElement submitnextnext = (HTMLAnchorElement)myDoc.all.item("forwardTo1", 0);
                submitnextnext.click();
```

Can anyone help me to override this issue

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have posted?

Comment: can't able to select the Tab Section 1 and Section 3 (java script). Section 2 is in default state.